# Как обрезать формат видео с камеры в OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

Коллеги, подскажите: Необходимо подрезать верхнуюю половину снимаего с камеры видео, чтобы впоследствии обрабатывалась и выводилась на экран нижняя половина снимаемого видео. С помощью `sub_frame=frame(Rect(0,0,x1,y1,);` подрезать только нижнюю половину. При попытке присвоить первым двум аргументам Rect() иные значения, выводится исключение. 
Код ниже:

```
int main()
{
VideoCapture cap(0);

Mat frame;
Mat sub_frame;
Mat frame_gray;
Mat frame_blur;
Mat frame_canny;
Mat frame_hough;
vector<Vec4i> lines;


namedWindow("Lane Detection", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (true)
{
    cap.read(frame);

    sub_frame=frame(Rect(0,0,1280,640));        
    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    GaussianBlur(frame_gray,frame_blur,Size(3,3),0);

    Canny(frame_blur,frame_canny,50,125,3);
    cvtColor(frame_canny,frame_hough,COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    HoughLinesP(frame_canny,lines,2,CV_PI/720,5,120,2);
    for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i l=lines[i];
        line (frame, Point(l[0],l[1]),Point (l[2],l[3]),Scalar(0,0,255), 4, LINE_AA);
    }

    imshow("Lane Detection",sub_frame);
    if (waitKey(10)==27)
    {break;}
 }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить ROI с координатами и скопировать в меньший размер.

```
sub_frame = frame(Rect(0, yshift, width, height - yshift));
```